# como visualisar una subconsulta mientras se ve la web sin apliacr submit

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Explico si al crear esta web, seleciono de una tabla:

Tabla sr_productos

```
id nombre_esp
1  NombreA
2  NombreB
3  NombreC
4  NombreD
```

el id 1 quien que en la parte de textarea marque el resultado de inmediado en la variable:

```
$id_producto2
```

El detalle es que no se como hacerlo me imagino es con un Include o un Require si alguien me ayuda lo agradesco

```
  <?php
include "../../includes/db_connect2.php"; 
include "../../includes/db_connect_mysql.php";
$id_producto2                = $_POST['id_producto2'];
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['id_producto2'])) {die('no ingresastes tu ID de GM!');}

}
?>

      <html>
            <head>
                <title>web-Mall</title>
                    <script src="../../includes/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
            </head>
        <body>
        <center>
        <br><br>
        <h2>Agregar Items a la Web Mall</h2>
        <form action="<?php
        echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        ?>" method="POST">

        <?php
        $sql = mysqli_query($conexion,'
        select * from sr_productos WHERE precio = 0 and estado = \'ACTIVO\'
        ');if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0)
        {echo"Elija Premio 2: <select required name='id_producto2' >\n";  
        print"<option value=''>-------------***************Elija una Opcion******************-----------</option>\n";
        while ($temp = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
        {
        print"<option value='".$temp["id"]."'>".$temp["nombre_esp"]."</option>\n";
        }
        echo"  </select>\n"; }else{ echo"No hay datos";  } mysqli_free_result($sql);
        ?> 

        <textarea><?php $id_producto2 ?></textarea><!--Aqui quiero que muestre el resultado del Select sr_productos instantaneamente osea que si seleciono NombreB deberia aparecer aqui 2 al instante-->

        <p><input type="submit" value="Confirma" name="submit" /></p>
        </form>
        </center>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: he leído 2 o 3 veces tu pregunta pero sigo sin entender lo que realmente quieres... si lo podrías editar y explicar mejor cual es tu objetivo... quizás alguien te podría ayudar (mejor)

Comment: Listo bro Gracias la verdad no me di cuenta de que estaba incompleta la pregunta un millon xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ejemplo Sencillo con ajax:

```
 $.ajax({ 
     url : "consultasProducto.php", 
     type : "POST", 
     data : { 
         id_producto : $('my_select').val() 
     } , 
     success : function(html_respuesta){ 
         my_textarea.value = html_respuesta;
     }  
  });

 El código anterior debe llamarse cada vez que tu select cambie.
```

Comment: jajaja pensándolo bien no necesariamente tiene que ser en la misma tabla, eso dependerá tu modelo de base de datos, pero ahí va con la lógica. Quizás esta forma sea un poco brusca, como ves se trae toda la información. La tecnología Ajax puede ser una vía, pero debes tomar en cuenta el tiempo de respuesta de tu servidor. A la final, todo dependerá de tus necesidades.

Comment: Gracias men pero ajuro siu o si tiene que ser con Opcion Select y textarea pues son 18.000 Registros el option me da la ventaja de recortar ess registros desde otro Option Ademas ese script no lo entiendo u.u bo se si es o no otro option o algo asi por el estilo

Comment: Ajax sería la solución mas viable, solo tienes que mandar la consulta con los respectivos parámetros cada vez que el select cambie su valor. Adjunto link de un ejemplo de consulta Ajax con jQuery (https://cybmeta.com/ajax-con-json-y-php-ejemplo-paso-a-paso)

Comment: Míralo mejor la publicación editada